# Manipulate with generated controls for setting each bar in a bar chart

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, charts

I would like to create a list of parameters, then create a `Manipulate` with these parameters. Similar to this piece of code:

```
(* code that generates manipulate parameters *)
bars = Array[b, 5];
(* code that generates manipulate *)
Manipulate[
 BarChart[bars, PlotRange -> {0, 2}],
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, 0, 2} & /@ bars)]]
```

`Manipulate` displays 5 controls for `b[1]`..`b[5]`, but the `BarChart` always stays empty - I think `bars` isn't evaluated, but I couldn't figure out how to make `Manipulate` evaluate it.

This works, but isn't dynamic any more:

```
bars = Array[b, 5];
Manipulate[
 BarChart[{b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}],
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, 0, 2} & /@ bars)]]
```

(i.e. if the code above decides to create 4 or 6 entries in `bars` it won't work any more)

Comment: `With[{bars = bars}, Manipulate[BarChart[bars, PlotRange -> {0, 2}],  Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, 0, 2} & /@ bars)]] ]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject the evaluated `bars` with `With`:

```
With[{bars = bars},
 Manipulate[BarChart[bars, PlotRange -> {0, 2}], 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, 0, 2} & /@ bars)]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or with a function:

```
manFN = Function[bars, 
   Manipulate[BarChart[bars, PlotRange -> {0, 2}], 
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, 0, 2} & /@ bars)]]
   ];

manFN[Rest@bars] (* Rest@.. to show dependence on argument *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @nikie You're welcome!

Comment: @MichaelE2 For readability I prefer to not use `Evaluate`. One way is `With[{bars = bars,
  controls = Sequence @@ Map[{#, 0, 2} &]@bars},
 Manipulate[BarChart[bars, PlotRange -> {0, 2}], controls]]`